# Integrating Crashlytics in a multi-module project kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, crashlytics

I have an Android project with a main module plus multiple other sub-modules. I integrated Crashlytics in the project successfully, by updating the project-level build.gradle and the main module build.gradle but still I can't crash log in console

I tried with demo project with same package it was working fine but main project not working

1. Project build.gradle

   ```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository}
            }
            maven {  url "https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo" }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.1'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"
            classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-nexus-plugin:2.3.1'
            classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.7.1'
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                // Override the default version of ProGuard
                // with the most recent one.
                force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.2.0'
            }
        }

    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
            maven {  url "https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo" }
             flatDir {
                dirs 'libs','aar'
            }
        }


    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
    subprojects {
        gradle.projectsEvaluated {
            tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
                options.compilerArgs << '-Xmaxerrs' << '500'
            }
        }
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                    details.useVersion "26.1.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    2.Main Module build.gradle


    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'

        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
    }

    android {
        signingConfigs {
        }
        compileSdk 34
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'

        }
        defaultConfig {
            configurations.all {
                resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
            }
            applicationId "com.abc.testapp"
            minSdkVersion 24
            targetSdkVersion 34
            versionCode 277
            versionName "3.77"
            testApplicationId "com.abc.testapp.test"
            testInstrumentationRunner "com.abc.testapp.Instrumentation"
            multiDexEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Shellnet
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                debuggable false
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                firebaseCrashlytics {
                    nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
                    strippedNativeLibsDir "libs"
                    unstrippedNativeLibsDir "libs"
                }
                proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
                proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
                buildConfigField "String", "TEST_TAGS", "\"${getTestTags()}\""
            }
            debug {
                debuggable true
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                firebaseCrashlytics {
                    nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
                    strippedNativeLibsDir "libs"
                    unstrippedNativeLibsDir "libs"
                }
                proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
                proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
                buildConfigField "String", "TEST_TAGS", "\"${getTestTags()}\""

            }
        }

        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
        sourceSets {
            androidTest {
                assets.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/assets']
            }
        }

        productFlavors {
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
        implementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
        implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.4.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.4.0'
        implementation project(':sub')

        androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.5.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
        androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0') {
            exclude module: 'support-annotations'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
            exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        }

        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:18.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
        implementation 'com.firebase:digitsmigrationhelpers:0.1.1'
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
        implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


        implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '5.0.0-alpha.2'
        implementation group: 'com.squareup.okio', name: 'okio', version: '3.0.0-alpha.6'

        // Branch required
        implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:5.2.6'
        implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.1.0'
        // Chrome Tab matching (enables 100% guaranteed matching based on cookies)
        implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'

        // Unit testing using cucumber
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.6'
        androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.6'
        testImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.6'

        // Facebook SDK
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:11.0.0'
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:11.0.0'

        // Add the Firebase Crashlytics and Analytics SDK.
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.2.12'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.1.0'

        /*Issue from google play store
        com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0*/
        implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth') {
            exclude module: "play-services-safetynet"
        }
    }

    def getTestTags() {
        return project.hasProperty("tags") ? project.getProperties().get("tags") : ""
    }
   ```

Comment: Actually sub-modules are not a problem, If you have successfully integrated in your main module then it should work as expected, may be you left something to add in your code, could you share build.gradle code and manifest code for further reference?

Comment: 1. Project build.gradle and manifest code update